# Predicate build with NET Core and EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Very quick question :

I'm trying to create a predicate builder like this :

```
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MyObject>();
```

But seems that is not available in **Net Core** And **EF Core**.

Am I missing a package or something ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sure that the `PredicateBuilder` you were using was not a custom class? A `PredicateBuilder` is shipped as part of [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) but the [source is also available here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) as follows:

```cs
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no `Cast`method in dotnet core. How do you use this code ?

Comment: Ok, I found : it is a extension method present in System.Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Here is also a solution, it can parse a string expression to lambda expression like this

```cs
Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> predicate 
    = Interpreter.ParsePredicate<Entity>("id = 1 and name='Test'").Result;
```

Refer to https://github.com/linhnle/Kkts.Expressions

Comment: Hi, you come up with your own library here, which is OK and appropriate in the light of this question, but it's always good to mention explicitly that you're the creator/contributor. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63957725/861716) a good example how to do this.